# Can't get this class with template to work?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write something like a C# interface in C++ with a generic object but i can't get it work.
every time i create a new instance in the main i get the following error:
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AccountRepository::AccountRepository(void)"

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "AccountRepository.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    AccountRepository repo;

    return 0;
}
```

*IRepository.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class Entity>
class IRepository
{
public:
    virtual bool add(Entity entity) = 0;
    virtual bool update(Entity entity) = 0;
    virtual Entity getById(int Id) = 0;
    virtual bool remove(Entity entity) = 0;
    virtual vector<Entity> getAll() = 0;
};
```

*AccountRepository.h*

```
#pragma once
#include "IRepository.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <vector>

class AccountRepository : public IRepository<Account>{
private:
    vector<Account> _accounts;

public:
    AccountRepository();
    ~AccountRepository();

    virtual bool add(Account entity) override;
    virtual bool update(Account entity) override;
    virtual Account getById(int Id) override;
    virtual bool remove(Account entity) override;
    virtual vector<Account> getAll() override;

};
```

*AccountReposity.cpp*

```
#include "AccountRepository.h"

inline AccountRepository::AccountRepository()
{

}

inline AccountRepository::~AccountRepository()
{

}

inline bool AccountRepository::add(Account entity)
{
    _accounts.push_back(entity);
    return true;
}

inline bool AccountRepository::update(Account entity)
{
    for (Account account : _accounts){
        if (account.getId() == entity.getId()){
            account.setName(entity.getName());
            account.setDescription(entity.getDescription());
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

inline Account AccountRepository::getById(int Id)
{
    for (Account account: _accounts)
    {
        if (account.getId() == Id)
            return account;
    }
}

inline bool AccountRepository::remove(Account entity)
{
    vector<Account>::iterator it;
    for (it = _accounts.begin(); it != _accounts.end(); ++it){
        if (it->getId() == entity.getId())
        {
            _accounts.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

inline vector<Account> AccountRepository::getAll()
{
    return _accounts;
}
```

Comment: `IRepository` should have a virtual destructor, but that's not your bug.

Comment: Why did you declare all of those functions as `inline`?

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing the `inline` keyword.  Treat it as if it means "the implementation for this function is in the header".

This immediately reveals the problem: You have a lot of `inline` functions in one of your cpp files, which is not a header.  Each cpp file that uses an `inline` function is *required* to either contain or include a definition of that function.  The problem is that the linkers do magic things with `inline` functions because they're supposed to be one copy in each of many cpp files.  So the compiler compiles `main.cpp`, and (since main doesn't know the function is inlined, notes that later the linker should link in the default constructor).  The compiler then compiles `AccountReposity.cpp`, sees that an inline function is not used, and so just skips it. Later then the linker has trouble finding a copy of `AccountRepository()` to use, and it reports an error. If the function body was defined in the header properly, it would have been instantiated into `main.cpp` during the compilation step, before it gets to the linking stage.

The fact that *some* compilers treat `inline` functions special doesn't really affect the rule-of-thumb at all.  Other compilers don't give `inline` functions any special optimization, and thinking of it as an optimization causes the error you encountered.  Ignoring the optimization makes it clearer where the keyword goes.

Comment: @dyp: The linker is responsible for _the link error_.  However, the _cause_ is UB because each ODR use blah blah blah.  I also noticed that and edited.  Trying to explain both the cause and the effects in novice-friendly language is tricky.

Comment: I don't think your answer is bad, I'm just a bit confused about certain details such as *"so it expects that the cpps that use them should each have their own (identical) copy"*. As far as I can tell, the linker does not know the function is `inline` - it sees two object files. Only in the TU of one of them has the function been declared `inline`. In the other TU, the *compiler* (presumably) assumes the function is *not* inline.

Comment: @dyp: I laid out all the details, should be complete now.

Comment: Hmm I think I should take that back. The linker has to know something about the function, since it needs to select one instance rather than reporting a duplicate symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare the member functions of `AccountRepository` as `inline`, you have to make them known in all translation units that use them, as per [basic.def.odr]/3:

> (...) An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

Either remove the `inline` from the function definitions or move them all to the header.